# Freebsd is not RECV the packet, although successfully sent

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, freebsd, raw-sockets

I have a new problem with the migration to freebsd. I've tried to give everything I can.
The problem with recvfrom is it just can't wait for a packet, even when I remove the timeout.

Here is a screenshot from wireshark which shows that the packets are sent successfully, and the packets from the host side are also sent successfully in response.

[image: Wireshark]

Here is the function I receive packets with, on linux it works on freebsd it refuses, I think this is a feature of RAW sockets on freebsd, with TCP protocol.

```c
int recv_tcp_packet(const char* dest_ip, int recv_timeout_ms, unsigned char** buffer) {
    /* Set target. */
    struct in_addr dest;
    dest.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_ip);

    /* Temporary buffer */
    unsigned char* read_buffer = *buffer;

    /* Creation sock. */
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1) {
#ifdef PRINT_ERRORS
        perror("recv_tcp_packet/create-socket-error");
#endif
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set timeout on socket. */
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = recv_timeout_ms / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (recv_timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000;
    int result = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    if (result == -1) {
#ifdef PRINT_ERRORS
        perror("recv_tcp_packet/setsockopt-error(timeout)");
#endif
        /* Timeout. */
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr saddr;
    time_t start_time = time(NULL);

    /* Infinite loop, on accepting all ICMP packets. */
    for (;;) {
        /* Updating the IP size with each new packet. */
        int saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
        int data_size = recvfrom(sock, read_buffer, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, &saddr, (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
        if (data_size == -1) {
#ifdef PRINT_ERRORS
            perror("recv_tcp_packet/recvfrom-error");
#endif
            close(sock);
            return -1;
        }

        /* Creating an IP stub to verify packet sorting. */
        struct ip_header* iph = (struct ip_header*)read_buffer;
        unsigned short iphdrlen = (iph->ihl) * 4;
        if (iphdrlen < 20) {
            close(sock);
            return -1;
        }

        /* Verification of the received packet's protocol. */
        if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP) {
            close(sock);
            return -1;
        }

        /* Obtains the sender's IP from the RECEIVED packet. */
        struct sockaddr_in source;
        memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
        source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

        /* Comparing the IP from the received packet with the IP
         * to which the packet was sent. */
        if (source.sin_addr.s_addr != dest.s_addr) {
            time_t current_time = time(NULL);
            int elapsed_time = (int)(current_time - start_time) * 1000;

            /* Timeout on a windowless loop where packets are received. */
            if (elapsed_time >= recv_timeout_ms) {
#ifdef PRINT_ERRORS
                printf("recv_tcp_packet/timeout: a timeout on the packet receiving loop has occurred.\n");
#endif
                close(sock);
                return -1;
            }
            continue;
        } else {
#ifdef PACKET_TRACE
            struct tcp_header* tcph = (struct tcp_header*)read_buffer;
            char ip_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(source.sin_addr.s_addr), ip_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("TCP & RCVD %d bytes from %s: ttl=%d ident=%d window=%d seq=%d sum=%d\n",
                   (int)sizeof(&iph) + (int)sizeof(&tcph), ip_str, iph->ttl, iph->id, tcph->window, tcph->seq, iph->check);
#endif

            /* Success read, fill the buffer. */
            *buffer = read_buffer;
            close(sock);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /* Ну ок :) */
    close(sock);
    return -1;
}
```

It just waits for the packet windowlessly, starting with recvfrom. She's not even accepting them.

Moreover, the logic of accepting ICMP packets works successfully for me.

I also tried writing acceptance via pcap, but it was the same there, I didn't have the code saved with pcap.

Comment: From the answer in the duplication question: "in BSD you can't receive anything that has a handler (like TCP and UDP)."

Comment: If you want to sniff TCP or UDP, you'll need to used BPF.

Comment: How sending is related to receiving a packet?

Comment: I don't think it's related in raw sockets.

Comment: I think you can send anything, but if there's a kernel module processing the received protocol, those packets won't be received by a raw socket.

Comment: Maybe, but how to fix it, I don't even have pcap wanting to accept anything.

Comment: Use BPF for packet capturing.

Comment: BPF on Freebsd? That's what pcap is.

Comment: "What is the BPF? The Berkeley Packet Filter is one of FreeBSD's most impressive devices. It provides you full (“raw”) access to your NICs data link layers, i.e. you are totally protocol-independent."

Comment: From https://bastian.rieck.me/blog/posts/2009/bpf/

Comment: Libcap uses /dev/bpf for *BSD, and RAW recvfrom for linux and others.

Comment: So that's what you should use. I think we just got confused on terminology.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try again, but the pcap library uses BPF for freebsd when receiving packets, otherwise protocol independence is not possible. It reads directly from the network interface itself.

Comment: Are you trying to say that your code already uses libcap and it's not working? I thought you were using ordinary raw sockets.